# Strange MySQL error to insert query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a row into a table in mysql.This should be simple, but for some reason I'm getting an unexpected response. This is the query I am trying to execute:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (testuser, testuseratdomaincom, testpass)
```

My table looks like so: http://pastebin.com/RmLZHWW8

However, when I run the query I get this response:

```
Failed to execute SQL : SQL INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (testuser, testuseratdomaincom, testpass) failed : Unknown column 'testuser' in 'field list'
```

It's trying to find a column called 'testuser' which should be the value for the username column. What is going on?

Comment: You need to wrap the values in single quote `values ('testuser', 'testuseratdomaincom', 'testpass')`

Answer (score 1):

the values should have quotes before and after.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your values like 'testuser'.
Your current query searches for a field 'testuser' in the table 'users' for inserting it into 'username'.

Correct query:

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('testuser', 'testuseratdomaincom', 'testpass')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put your values in quotes.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('testuser', 'testuseratdomaincom', 'testpass');
```